# Mounting Windows disk

Tags: mount

My new laptop has been hacked with a virus which I cannot remove.  I have loaded Ubuntu on a data stick and can boot ubuntu but it does not recognize the local pc hard drive (SSD - Dell Inspiron running windows 10).  When I do an lsblk, it lists all of the partitions on the USB drive.  I can connect to network drives on my network but just not the local pc drive.  The intent is to connect to the local pc drive, then wipe the drive and then reinstall windows... only if I can get to the local drive.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "Hacked with a virus" - without knowing the virus, or your system setup, it's impossible to answer this question.  Typically, Dell laptops come with RAID+AHCI mode enabled in the BIOS, and Ubuntu cannot read SSDs in this format.  Go into your BIOS and change the SATA mode to AHCI only, and then reboot into Ubuntu and see if it sees the local Windows drive.

Comment: It is as Thomas Ward indicated. However, you probably could just reinstall windows and during that installation make sure the drive is wiped, or wipe it through your bios setup.

Comment: Thomas was right on the setting in BIOS.  Now I can see the local drive so I can reload Windows.  Thanks!